# Proving that the space of sequences with bounded partial sums is complete

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X=\big\{x=\{x_i\} \subseteq \Bbb R : \big| \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \big| \leq C_x$ for all $N\big\}$ the space of sequences with bounded partial sums, and let $\|x\|=\sup_N |\sum_{i=1}^N x_i|$ for all $x \in X$. I need to prove $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ is complete.

MY TRY: (I tried to adapt like the proof that $l^\infty$ is complete) Let $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$, with $s_n = \{x_{ni}\}_{i=1}^\infty \subseteq \Bbb R$. For each $n \in \Bbb N$, there is a $C_n \in \Bbb R$ such that $\left| \sum_{i=1}^N x_{ni} \right| \leq C_n$ for all $N$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, there is $M \in \Bbb N$ such that $d(s_n, s_m)<\epsilon$  for all $n, m \geq M$. Then+ for each $K \in \Bbb N$,
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
\left| \sum_{i=1}^K \left(x_{ni}-x_{mi} \right) \right| \leq \sup_N \left| \sum_{i=1}^N \left(x_{ni}-x_{mi} \right) \right|=d(s_n, s_m)<\epsilon,
\end{equation}
for all $n, m \geq M$. This means that for each $K \in \Bbb N$, the sequence $\left\{\sum_{i=1}^K x_{ni}\right \}_{n=1}^\infty \subseteq \Bbb R$ is Cauchy. Since $\Bbb R$ is complete, for each $K \in \Bbb N$ there is a $y_K \in \Bbb R$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^K x_{ni} = y_K$. Let $s = \{y_K\}_{K=1}^\infty$. We'll prove that $s \in X$ and that $s_n \to s$. From (1), we have that when $n \to \infty$,
\begin{equation} \tag{2}
\left|y_K - \sum_{i=1}^K x_{mi} \right|  \leq \epsilon,
\end{equation}
for all $m \geq N$ y $K \in \Bbb N$.
Then, for a fixed $m \geq N$, we have that for each $K \in \Bbb N$
$$|y_K| \leq \left|y_K -  \sum_{i=1}^K x_{mi}+  \sum_{i=1}^K x_{mi} \right| \leq  \left|y_K - \sum_{i=1}^K x_{mi} \right| +  \left| \sum_{i=1}^K x_{mi} \right| < \epsilon + C_m.$$
This proves that the sequence $\{y_K\}_{K=1}^\infty$ is bounded.

Here's where I'm stuck, since the fact that a sequence is bounded doesn't imply that the partial sums of the sequence are bounded. I think there's something I have to change of the proof that $l^\infty$ is complete, but I can't find out what it is.

Comment: What distance are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I already added it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to change your norm and have $sup \sum |x_i|$ ?

Comment: @Thomas I'm pretty sure I don't

Comment: You may want to have your candidate limit be $(y_1, y_2-y_1, y_3-(y_1+y_2),...)$ instead of $(y_1,y_2,y_3,...)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach which sidesteps the issues above:

Let $i: X \to l_\infty$ be defined by $i(x) = (x_1, x_1+x_2, x_1+x_2+x_3,...)$.
It is clear that $\|x\|_X = \|i(x)\|_{\infty}$. Furthermore, $i$ is invertible, with $i^{-1}(y) = (y_1, y_2-y_1, y_3-(y_1+y_2),...)$.

Completeness follows because the mapping is an isometry.

Comment: Great! Thanks :)